# How to set column colors, title colors , font size , font family in external css file for highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

I want to make a seperate css file for all type of attributes like title colors, font size, font family, column colors, stack colors, pie colors. So no need to change these css in all pages, just change in css file and it will apply to all charts in all pages. Any solution for this.

Comment: Can you provide a short demo of two column charts ?

Comment: You need to define styles by javascript (like Theme) instaed of using CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own Highcharts theme and apply it to all of your charts.

http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/themes